# What does cron error "exit status 4" mean in syslog? (Ubuntu)

Tags: 7, cron, status-messages

I've never seen this before, my Status Report page says the last cron run was 35 minutes ago at 10:35 today. So I went to watchdog logs and could see that `Cron run completed` at `10:30`.

I've set the cron to run on `0` and `30`th minutes of every hour, so twice per hour using `sudo crontab -e` so it's using the root user's crontab with the following command (cron key intentionally removed):

```
0,30    * *   *   *     wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/cron.php?cron_key=
```

I'm not using the `cron.module` aka `poormanscron` in D6

I've manually run the cron and it updated the Status Report page after that.

What could cause this weird behavior? I'll admit that I haven't tried flushing the caches, but could caching be the cause of this? Or is there something more sinister?

---

I've dug around in syslog and found an error relating to the cron, but I have no idea what this means (cron key intentionally removed):

```
Aug 16 10:30:01 drupal-1 CRON[31372]: (root) CMD (wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost/cron.php?cron_key=)
Aug 16 10:30:01 drupal-1 CRON[31370]: (CRON) error (grandchild #31372 failed with exit status 4)
```

I can see the `grandchild #31372` is referring to the first line `CRON[31372]` but what does `exit status 4` mean?

I just wanted to also let people know that the cron has run without any problems so far afaik. But it could be that this is the first time I've noticed this as well.

Comment: Do you have a 'proper' cron set up or are you using the built-in auto-cron? If it's the latter, it just means that from 10:30 no-one visited the site until 10:35, so the auto-cron didn't get invoked

Comment: @Clive I've updated the question

Comment: Hmm might be worth checking the syslog to check that cron job was fired off properly (I'm sure it will have been, just a good idea to make sure). I can't remember if the 'last ran' is the time at the start of the cron job or the end - if it's at the end, and the job had a max execution time of 300 seconds, and perhaps timed out, that figure might make sense

Comment: @Clive updated the question with syslog message. It shows that the cron started at 10:30:01 and errored out at the same time, so it couldn't have been a timeout.

Comment: I'm almost positive status 4 for wget is a network error, so it may just have been a temporary network problem. Or server config might have changed and http://localhost might not resolve locally any more. Either way the easiest test is to run the command manually and see if it exits with an error again. If not, I _think_ you're safe to assume it was an intermittent internal network problem

Comment: You're probably right, I can't see the manual cron run in syslog but I can see the previous ones which had run successfully. Fingers crossed it was a temporary network issue. Thanks @Clive. What can I do to this question? Vote to close? Or if you can put up an answer I can award you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm such an idiot sometimes.

I've edited the `.htaccess` file this morning to redirect without `www.` to `www.domain.com` and that has caused my cron going to `localhost` to be redirected to `www.localhost` which caused the cron to fail. /facepalm

But to answer `exit status 4`'s meaning for `wget` according to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) it means `Network failure` (Kudos to @Clive)